# How to obtain the body response in the client-side?

Tags: javascript, html, http, xmlhttprequest, response

I am new in web, I am serving an html when a button is clicked on the client side through a request, the body response of that request is the html. How can I retrieve the html or body response from the client side?

I am trying with this code but everything is empty:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open(signedRequest.method, signedRequest.url, true);
 console.log('xhr.response: ', xhr.response);
 console.log('xhr.responseText: ', xhr.responseText);
 console.log('xhr.responseXML: ', xhr.responseXML);
 document.write('<p>xhr: ' + xhr + '</p>');
 xhr.send();
```

Any idea on how to obtain the body response in the client-side?

Comment: So the responseText does not have the content? Are you running into CORS problem?

Comment: Note: synchronous requests are a bad idea. You should ideally use fetch.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello for your comments, I'm not running into CORS problem, the html is served but I can't obtain the body response. I'll switch to fetch, thanks.

Comment: So the responseText has no content?

Comment: That's right, everything I print to the console shows as <empty string> except for responseXML which shows as null

Comment: `https://httpbin.org/get` Try to send a `GET` request to this URL

Comment: @frankh07 Did you have a look at the answer I provided?

Comment: The issue is you don't have an event handler part when the XMLhttp request is completed. You just sent a request to the server, but where do you deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a div or any input element with the id "demo" and try to run the code below.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<strong>The response from the test URL is: </strong>" + this.responseText;
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.response));
   }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://httpbin.org/get", true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry @Dream Bold  i´m having issues with XMLHttpRequest request, maybe do you know how to obtain the body response from a fetch request? I'm tryng with .then((response) => {console.log(response.body); }) but didn't work.

Comment: What kind of data do you expect from the server?

Comment: I encrypt the html on the server side and I need to encrypt the html that reaches the client to verify that it hasn't been modified, so I try to retrieve the body of the response to the html request.

Comment: `console.log(this.response);` You can try this in the above code in `if` statement.